# SwiftUI: Render one object in preview and another on device

Tags: ios, swiftui

I was attempting to do something like this:

```
        #if DEBUG
            Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        #else
            // render camera view
        #endif
```

But I would really like to do something like so:

```
        #if PREVIEW
            Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        #else
            // render camera view
        #endif
```

I was hoping that the preview window would then display only the black background (because Camera is not supported in preview, of course), and then to display the camera when I run the project on my physical device.

However, it appears that `DEBUG` is true whenever you're not running in `Release` mode. I thought about adding a `isPreview` parameter to the constructor with a default of `false` and passing `true` inside of the view's `PreviewProvider`, but this seems like a backwards way to do it.

**Is there an equivalent of `#if DEBUG` for Preview only?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like it, but it appears one way to do it is to set a file-wide variable `isPreview`, instantiate it to `false` and then change it to `true` inside the `PreviewProvider`'s `previews` method, and then conditionally render Views based on the value.

Instantiate the value and change it inside the `PreviewProvider`

```
fileprivate var isPreview = false

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        isPreview = true
        return MyView()
    }
}
```

And then use it to conditionally render something inside `MyView`:

```
 if(isPreview) {
    // render only in preview
 } else {
   // render only in simulator and device
 }
```

I hope someone knows a cleaner way.